# Ограничение доступа к пользовательскому типу в REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Каким образом можно предоставлять доступ только с логином и паролем определённым записям кастомного типа в WordPress? Причём, для определённого пользователя должны быть доступны только записи, которые он сам создал, если это не администратор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Каким образом можно предоставлять доступ только с логином и паролем
> определённым записям кастомного типа в WordPress?

По умолчанию в ВП нельзя ограничить доступ пользователя "к определённым" записям. ВП использует политику "возможностей" используемых "ролями". См https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/

Управление доступом ролей к кастомным типам постов задаётся в `register_post_type` аргументами  `capability_type`, `capabilities` и `map_meta_cap`.
См https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type#capabilities

> Причём, для определённого пользователя должны быть доступны только
> записи, которые он сам создал, если это не администратор.

Пользователи с ролью "автор" имеют возможности редактирования только своих записей.

И ещё. С версии 5.6 в ВП появилась возможность задавать пароли приложения. Это позволит не светить реальные пароли пользователей и управлять ими независимо.
См https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest/basic/authentication/application-passwords

Comment: О, то, что надо. Спасибо.